# IntellIj IDEA: not able to navigate to Advised Methods from the Advice method in Aspect class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, aspectj

I am using AspectJ and IntellIj 2020.1. I am unable to navigate to the joint point from one of the advice methods by clicking on the "m" symbol beside it, whereas I could do so with other methods.

Structure of my @Aspect class
[image]

Here the advice "thisWorks" is able to navigate the pointcut (Profile.retrieve()) whereas method "doesntWork" can't navigate to "Client.retrieve(), shows "this advice advices no method"

Class Profile :

[image]

Class Client which implements interface ClientSuper :
[image]

Both the classes' objects are initialized by Spring bean configuration and this is a Gradle project.

Could you help me detect the cause of this behaviour? I couldn't find anything that works after 1 hour of research.

Comment: Feedback, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, whatever IDEA does, your first advice probably does not work during runtime because you have `returning = "profileInfo"` but no `profileInfo` advice method parameter. Instead, you have `validatingCarrier` which does not even occur in the pointcut.

Other than that, IMO IDEA's AspectJ and Spring AOP support is something that was started long ago with an initial blast of big enthusiasm and then never really finished. I tried, the cross-referencing stuff does not work for me at all in a Spring AOP project, no matter which pointcut I use. As much as I dislike Eclipse as an IDE in general, at least this stuff works for native AspectJ (never tried Spring AOP there, though). Maybe you should search the bug database at JetBrains and/or file a bug by yourself. If this is somehow meant to work, it eludes me how to configure it in order to do so.

Sorry to not have any better news. I do hope that someone else has.